# How to focus textfield by default in tvOS application, not first responder?

Tags: swift, tvos

I have 2 pages registration and login, When i come back to registration page from login by pressing back button i want to make focus to text field by default. How to do that in `viewWillAppear` method? I have tried methods `updateFocusIfNeeded, setNeedsFocusUpdate , canBecomeFocused` , but nothing is working.

Comment: use [textfield becomeFirstResponder];

Answer (score 1):

Override `preferredFocusedView` in the view controller and return your text field from it.

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
  return textField
}
```

Then call `setNeedsFocusUpdate` and `updateFocusIfNeeded` when you want the text field to become focused (in `viewWillAppear` as you described).